# How to set up a public Git repository in Unix

Tags: unix, git, repository

I've set up a number of private repos where I commit via SSH but I'm having problems setting up a public one. Here's what I've done so far:

Log into my server via ssh

```
$ cd public_html/repos/
$ mkdir test
$ cd test 
$ git --bare init
$ touch git-daemon-export-ok # tell GIT it's ok to export this project
$ chmod 777 -R ../test #making sure the directory had full read write execute permissions
$ exit # exit out of ssh

$ mkdir test_porject
$ cd test_project
$ touch README.txt
$ git init #Initialized empty Git repository in ~/test_porject
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
$ git remote add origin http://repos.mydomain.com/test
$ git push origin master
```

this is the error I get:
error: The requested URL returned error: 500 while accessing http://repos.mydomain.com/test/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed

Huh???? Not sure why this isn't working. If you go to http://repos.mydomain.com/ I don't get any errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you see in your server error log?  This will usually include more detailed information about the 500 error.

Comment: Here's what I get:  [22/Sep/2011:13:08:36 -0400] "GET /test/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 500 680 "-" "git/1.7.4.1"
[22/Sep/2011:13:08:36 -0400] "GET /test/info/refs HTTP/1.1" 500 680 "-" "git/1.7.4.1"

Comment: What do you see in your browser if you go to http://repos.mydomain.com/test/info/refs?  What about just http://repos.mydomain.com/test/?  Do either of these work?  I'm a little puzzled because you're installing things into your `public_html` directory, which is often accessed via `/~username/`, but maybe that's just how your hosting provider does things.

Comment: I can access refs just fine in the bowser. I made a subdomain for all my repositories which is located here: /home/usename/public_html/repos.

Comment: I'm currently getting this error `$ git clone http://mydomain:[port]/home/username/public_html/repos/test 
Cloning into test...
error:  while accessing http://mydomain:[port]/home/username/public_html/repos/test/info/refs`

Comment: With http:// your path to repository should be relative to root directory of corresponding virtual host, not to the root of server's file system. And show what you get in error log, there may be some more detailed info about error 500.

Comment: You should check the error.log of your webserver, not che access.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suspicious that your transcript above does not in fact represent
the actual commands that you typed.  Here's how you can set up an
http-accessible repository, and the commands (and output) here are
exactly what I have typed in:

Creating the repository:

```
$ mkdir -p public_html/git
$ cd public_html/git
$ git init --bare testrepo.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/lars/public_html/git/testrepo.git/
$ cd testrepo.git
$ mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update
$ chmod 755 hooks/post-update
```

Populating it with some commits:

```
$ cd ~/tmp/
$ mkdir testrepo
$ cd testrepo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/lars/tmp/testrepo/.git/
$ echo this is a test > myfile
$ git add myfile
$ git ci -m 'added myfile'
[master (root-commit) eea6564] added myfile
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 myfile
$ git remote add origin ~/public_html/git/testrepo.git
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 233 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To /home/lars/public_html/git/testrepo.git/
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Cloning it via http:

```
$ cd ~/tmp
$ git clone http://localhost/~lars/git/testrepo.git testrepo-cloned
Cloning into testrepo...
$ ls -A testrepo-cloned/
.git  myfile
```

If you run through this and it doesn't work, I strongly suspect an
issue with your webserver configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> $ git remote add origin http://repos.mydomain.com/test
>
> $ git push origin master

You are trying to push to an http exposed repository? This won't work.

http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_public_repository.html

> [..] Anybody else should then be able to **clone** or **pull** from that URL [..]